# Sharparchitecture upgrade from 1.5 to 1.9 error

Tags: sharp-architecture

I have upgraded SharpArchitecture from 1.5 to 1.9.

I have followed the guide here http://blog.sharparchitecture.net/post/Sharp-Architecture-19-released.aspx, and ensured that I have set "copy local = true" for the various DLLs,
but I still receive the following error when running the site:

```
Exception Details: System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to
access an element as a type incompatible with the array.

Source Error:

Line 35:             log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
Line 36:             ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
Line 37:             ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AreaViewEngine());
Line 38:
Line 39:             ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new
SharpModelBinder();

Source File: xxx.Web
\Global.asax.cs    Line: 37

Stack Trace:

[ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type
incompatible with the array.]
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item) +62
   xxx.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in

[HttpException (0x80004005): Attempted to access an element as a type
incompatible with the array.]

System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
context, HttpApplication app) +3988565
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +325

System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
appContext, HttpContext context) +407
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
appContext) +375

[HttpException (0x80004005): Attempted to access an element as a type
incompatible with the array.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
+11529072
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
+141

System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
wr, HttpContext context) +4784373
```

Does anyone knwo what I might have forgotten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking at the versions of SharpArchitecture in the different project several times, but apparently I had missed one project which didn't have the SharpArch DLL set to Specific Version.